# using algebraic topological method to solve a complex analysis problem

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $f \colon D^{2} \to D^{2}$ be a continuous function, and view $D^{2}$ as the set of complex numbers with norm $\leq 1$.
>   Assume that on the boundary, $f \colon \partial D \to \partial D$ is given by $f(z) = z^{7}$.
>   Show that there is a $z_{0} \in D$ with $f(z_{0}) = 0$.
>   More generally, show that $f$ is surjective.

This question appears in the book of algebraic topology.
I feel so helpless.
I think we can use the functor to translate the geometric problem to the algebraic problem.

Comment: This problem isn't really about complex analysis at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all note that $z \mapsto z^7$ is nonzero in the fundamental group of $S^1$. This is equivalent to saying that this map can not be extended to $D^2$.

Now suppose that your map $f$ is not surjective, therefore it factors through $D^2-\{x_0\}$, where $x_0$ is some point in the interior of $D^2$. But now $D^2-\{x_0\}$ has $S^1$ as a deformation retract with retraction $r\colon D^2-\{x_0\} \to S^1$. But now $r \circ f$ is an extension of $z \mapsto z^7$ onto $D^2$, which contradicts the fact stated in the beginning.

Comment: Since $f$ is a continuous function on the $D^{2}$,$f$ is the extension of the restriction of boundary of $D$. Is this contradicting to the argument above?

Comment: The point is that you can extend a map from $S^1$ to $S^1$ always to a map from $D^2$ to $D^2$, but the point here is that we can extend the map $z \mapsto z^7$ as a map from $S^1$ to $S^1$ to a map from $D^2$ to $S^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation.